# Underscore added to href in URL in outlook message

Tags: html, exchange-server, rtf, email-formats

when my website sends an email to a client to reset their password they get a link for them to click on.

The link in the email text looks good

i.e.

http://mywebaddress.com/Home/ActionPasswordResetRequest/f3d0wE8T

but when they click it (or when I view the underlying href, there is an extra underscore in the address, which causes an error: i.e.

http://mywebaddress.com/Home/a_ctionPasswordResetRequest/f3d0wE8T

It keeps happening for just one client.

Any idea why this might be happening? Could it be something at the client's exchange server end which would be doing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume the client's email host or something else has added that underscore. They were using yahoo. Seems like a one off incident though. So something unique to that client's email set up!